# Indexing a dataframe based on date element of datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please consider:

```
In : df
Out:

date
2017-12-01 00:00:00   2641.500
2017-12-01 00:05:00   2641.750
2017-12-01 00:10:00   2641.750
2017-12-01 00:15:00   2641.500
2017-12-01 00:20:00   2641.500
Name: o, dtype: float64
```

**Question**: I wish to subset the df by indexing by the dates only and not time (`2017-12-01`).

**I do**:

```
only_dates = pd.Series([x.date() for x in df.index.normalize()]).unique()
```

which seems to work:

```
In : only_dates 
Out:
array([datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)], dtype=object)
```

**Issue**: However, when I try to index the df using `only_dates`:

```
In : df[only_dates] 
Out:
date
2017-12-01   2641.500
Name: o, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, implicitly, it indexed only `2017-12-01 00:00:00`, while I wanted it to index `2017-12-01`, thus returning the entire `df` as `2017-12-01` is the date for the entire `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[df.index == df.index.normalize()]
print (df)
2017-12-01    2641.5
Name: o, dtype: float64
```

If want all rows:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = df.loc[df.index.date == datetime(2017, 12, 1).date()]
print (df)
2017-12-01 00:00:00    2641.50
2017-12-01 00:05:00    2641.75
2017-12-01 00:10:00    2641.75
2017-12-01 00:15:00    2641.50
2017-12-01 00:20:00    2641.50
Name: o, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to index a DataFrame, i believe you meant to index between a date range and for a single date also. 
May be this will work, pandas already have this stuff inbuilt.

```
df.loc['20171201':] # In this line if you add a next value after colon e.g.
# '20171201': '20171205' it will select rows between two dates 
date    
2017-12-01 00:00:00+00:00   2641.50
2017-12-01 00:05:00+00:00   2641.75
2017-12-01 00:10:00+00:00   2641.75
2017-12-01 00:15:00+00:00   2641.50
2017-12-01 00:20:00+00:00   2641.50
```